# LDAP-login FLASK

Tags: python, flask, active-directory, ldap

I am using FLASK_LDAP_AUTH for login system. I am checking a another server server AD to login. but when i run it only look at my local host ? also it keep saying following error 401 
{"error": "unauthorized", "message": "Please authenticate with a valid token", "status": 401}

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'somethingsecret'
app.config['LDAP_AUTH_SERVER'] = 'ldap://serverIP' 
app.config['LDAP_TOP_DN'] = 'ou=Users,dc=your_org,dc=TEST.domain'
app.register_blueprint(token, url_prefix='/auth')
```

In this link https://github.com/drowolath/flask-ldap-auth 
its say something with token which is not clear. Hope anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this auth project basically uses a token in lieu of a cookie to maintain auth in a session. Without a token, your authentication attempt is never even getting to the point of talking to the directory server. The verify_auth_token function fails with a bad signature error (specifically "BadSignature: No '.' found in value"). Without tracing, though, the only output you get is the 401 error that you see.

The authentication process is two step -- first obtain a token from the URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/request-token. Assuming valid credentials are supplied, the URL returns JSON containing the token. Depending on how you are *using* the token, you may need to base64 encode it (the [httpie example on the GitHub page](https://github.com/drowolath/flask-ldap-auth) handles this for you, but the example below includes the explicit encoding step).

You then *use* the token when accessing subsequent pages, for instance  http://127.0.0.1:5000/

```
import requests
import base64

API_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/request-token"
SITE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"

tupleAuthValues = ("userIDToTest", "P@s5W0Rd2T35t")

tokenResponse = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, auth=tupleAuthValues)

if(tokenResponse.status_code is 200):
        jsonResponse = tokenResponse.json()
        strToken = jsonResponse['token']
        print("The token is %s" % strToken)

        strB64Token = base64.b64encode(strToken)
        print("The base64 encoded token is %s" % strB64Token)

        strHeaders = {'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(strB64Token)}

        responseSiteAccess = requests.get(SITE_URL, headers=strHeaders)
        print(responseSiteAccess.content)
else:
        print("Error requesting token: %s" % tokenResponse.status_code)
```

Running the code above, you get:

```
[lisa@linux02 flask-ldap]# python authtest.py
The token is eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImV4cCI6MTUzODE0NzU4NiwiaWF0IjoxNTM4MTQzOTg2fQ.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImdhdXNzIn0.FCJrECBlG1B6HQJKwt89XL3QrbLVjsGyc-NPbbxsS_U:
The base64 encoded token is ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJbVY0Y0NJNk1UVXpPREUwTnpVNE5pd2lhV0YwSWpveE5UTTRNVFF6T1RnMmZRLmV5SjFjMlZ5Ym1GdFpTSTZJbWRoZFhOekluMC5GQ0pyRUNCbEcxQjZIUUpLd3Q4OVhMM1FyYkxWanNHeWMtTlBiYnhzU19VOg==
Hello, world
```